How in PhpStorm 2024 change background color of nonexisting class?
In PhpStorm having error with undefined class of my php code:

Where can I change of background color to see error more clearly ?
Now I can hardly distinguish  background color of error ...
I searched in setting options, but did not find.
I use latest PhpStorm 2024.2  version.

Step 1: Open Settings
Open the Settings dialog by pressing Ctrl + Shift + Alt + S (Windows/Linux) or Cmd + Shift + Alt + S (macOS).
Step 2: Navigate to Editor Settings
In the Settings dialog, navigate to Editor > Color Scheme > General.
Step 3: Find "Invalid Symbol" Highlighting
In the General settings, scroll down to the "Invalid symbol" section.
Step 4: Change Background Color
Click on the "Background" field and select a new color from the palette. You can also enter a custom color code.
Step 5: Apply Changes
Click "Apply" and then "OK" to close the Settings dialog.
Step 6: Restart PhpStorm (Optional)
If the changes don't take effect immediately, try restarting PhpStorm.
After following these steps, non-existent classes should be highlighted with the new background color you selected.
